# Why isn´t my featured image not saving when editing post?

Tags: magento-1.9, blog

I followed this tutorial to add a featured image to my blog post

https://forum.aheadworks.com/featured-image-t3821.html

I added the following code

```
if(isset($_FILES['featured_image']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['featured_image']['tmp_name']))) {
           try {
              $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('featured_image');
              $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
              $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

              // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file in a folder the magento way
              // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file directly in the $path folder
              $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

              $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;

              $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['featured_image']['name']);

              $data['featured_image'] = $_FILES['featured_image']['name'];
           }catch(Exception $e) {

           }
        }

        // handle delete image
        else {
           if(isset($data['featured_image']['delete']) && $data['featured_image']['delete'] == 1)
              $data['image_main'] = '';
           else
              unset($data['featured_image']);
        }
```

to the file

```
app/code/community/AW/Blog/controllers/Adminhtml/AWblog/Manage/BlogController.php
```

and it works you can go to the post, add the featured image, click save, it saves, but if you click save again it wipes out the featured image,

I added

```
$model->setFeaturedImage($_FILES['featured_image']['name']);
```

just before

```
$model->save();
```

but isn't making a difference, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please check in your form  `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' `

Comment: didn't make a difference, I assume add 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' to the field set of featured image

Comment: You have to add to this in your form

Comment: Its already added to the form :/

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);`  in the post and check what you get in post

Comment: Tried it printed an empty array()

Comment: ini_set('file_uploads'  , 'On' );  Write this line in your Form.php

Comment: added ini_set('file_uploads' , 'On' ); to the top of my form app/code/community/AW/Blog/Block/Manage/Blog/Edit/Tab/Form.php still same effect :/

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: Cheers worked a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add this code before `$model->save();`

```
  if($id){
    if($data['featured_image'] == "" ){
       $data['featured_image'] = $model->getData('featured_image'); 
    }
  }
```